# How to check if a pointer to an object is stored at a given index

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

This is an example of the header file for the first class named ClassA.h

```
class  ClassA { 

public:
    void functionA ; 

private: 
    int a; 
};
```

Example  of the headerfile  of Class B

```
#include "ClassA.h"
class ClassB {

public: 
   ClassA* functionB(int index) ; 
    ClassB (int s) {
   size = s; 
   pointer= new ClassA *[size] ; 
   } //Constructor  with  1D array  of  Objects implementation 

private:
  ClassA **pointer;  //1D  array which  has points to  objects  of ClassA  which  has  already been  implemented in the  constructor 
 int size; 
};
```

In order  to  implement  `functionB` I need  to  return  a pointer to the Object  `ClassA` only if it is  stored at a specific  index provided by the  user. How  would  I  go about  checking  if it  is stored  at  the specific  index?

Comment: Why do you hold an array as `ClassA**` though? Use `std::vector`, or `std::array` if you can use c++11

Comment: `return pointer[index];` presumably? Is this really what you're asking for?

Comment: Without question, you should be using std containers - almost certainly `std::vector`. If that's absolutely impossible, then you will need to also show how you allocate `pointer`, and you'll need to store its size somewhere. Basically re-writing `std::vector`.

Comment: `return *(pointer + index)`

Comment: I know  there  are  simpler  ways  to  implement this, however  my specification requires  it  to  be  1D pointer  to  the Object

Comment: Unless this is some kind of misguided school assignment, "1D pointer to the object" is not a sensible specification. Also what do you even mean by "IF it is stored at a specific index". Don't you just mean "the object at the specified index?"

Comment: @tenfour it  is  a school assignment. I need to  check whether  or not the Object is stored at the user  specified  object

Comment: The size and the allocation  of  the  pointer  is done  in the  constructor

Comment: I have the feeling you're not providing all the details. `pointer` is a pointer to a bunch of objects. The user just specifies the index. With just the index, you can return the object at the specified index, like @user657267 said. But your "...whether or not the object is stored ..." doesn't make much sense. Which object? Are you trying to figure out if the index is in bounds? Or points to a valid object? In any case, it all depends on how `pointer` is allocated, and populated. Which you don't show in your question.

Comment: @tenfour I added my constructor  implementation. I'm trying  to  figure  out  it points  to  a valid  object

Answer (score 0):

At no point do you actually instantiate any `ClassA` objects. In your constructor you allocate a bunch of pointers to `ClassA`, but you don't actually initialize them to anything. So there are never any valid objects in your array.